# wpf - Custom UserControl not being displayed in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, user-controls

I'm trying to create a datagrid which displays a custom usercontrol in a row. The datagrid will actually only have one column and when a new row is added, a new instance of that usercontrol should be displayed in the new row. I haven't implemented an add button as yet so I've temporarily set it up load an already created custom usercontrol. However, nothing comes up; only thing that is shown is the Column Header.

Here is my XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ColumnWidth="*" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="dgLOA">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Pay Advice">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:About/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set  a ItemSource to your DataGrid so the custom control will be displayed based on the count of itemsource,

```
 <Grid>
        <DataGrid ColumnWidth="*" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="dgLOA">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Pay Advice">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:MyControl/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

You have to set ItemSOurce either in the codebehind or in the xaml file like follows,

```
dgLOA.ItemsSource = GetEmployees();
```

in Xaml

ItemsSource="{Binding Employes}"

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try as soon as I get back on it

Comment: Ok, please let me know if u have any issues.